# SVG Animate in reverse once complete

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I've created a basic svg animation which loops every 750ms, however once it's finished a single animation loop it jumps back to the beginning giving it an ugly hard cut look.

```
<animate attributeName="stop-opacity" from="0.99" to="0.20" dur="750ms" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Is it possible that once the opacity goes from `0.99` down to `0.20` it will work its way back up to `0.99` instead of instantly jumping back to the start variable?

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gde5zup4/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can specify multiple values by using the `values` attribute on `animate`. Using this, you could specify to go back to the original opacity or even add more opacity values:

```
<animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0.99;0.20;0.99" dur="750ms" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Comment: Aha! I'm new to svg animation, this is exactly what I was after thank you

Answer (score 10):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gde5zup4/1/) is a working example. There is no out of the box way to have an animation go back and forth using SMIL, but you can use a workaround that starts a secondary animation after the first that is a backwards animation. This will loop and give the effect of your SVG fading in and out.

```
<animate id="anim1"attributeName="stop-opacity" from="0.99" to="0.20" dur="750ms" begin="0s; anim2.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animate id="anim2"attributeName="stop-opacity" from="0.20" to="0.99" dur="750ms" begin="anim1.end" fill="freeze"/>
```

Those are the two lines that I changed. Notice I have the second animation start once the first ends and the first one start after the second one ends (looping between the two).